# Cannot find where Segmentation fault happens

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The segmentation fault is happening in the function un() which returns the union of the two arrays.
But here's the complete code just in case.
I've tried adding some print statement in un() but it still displays Segmentation fault and nothing else.

I'm using GCC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input_set(int* set, int size) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", set+i);
        if(i != 0 && set[i] == set[i-1]) {
            printf("A set cannot have repeated values. Enter again!\n");
            i--;
        }
    }
}

void display_set(int *set, int size) {
    int i;

    printf("{ ");
    for(i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        printf("%d, ", set[i]);
    printf("%d }\n\n", set[size-1]);
}

int* difference(int *setA, int sizeA, int *setB, int sizeB, int *size) {
    int *setC = malloc(sizeof(int) * (sizeA < sizeB) ? sizeA : sizeB);
    int i, j, present = 0;
    *size = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < sizeB; j++)
            if(setA[i] == setB[j]) {
                present = 1;
                break;
            }
        if(!present)
            setC[(*size)++] = setA[i];
        present = 0;
    }

    return setC;
}

int* intersection(int *setA, int sizeA, int *setB, int sizeB, int *size) {
    int size1;
    int *set1 = difference(setA, sizeA, setB, sizeB, &size1);
    int *set2 = difference(setA, sizeA, set1, size1, size);

    return set2;
}

int* un(int *setA, int sizeA, int *setB, int sizeB, int *size) {
    int size1, size2, size3;
    int i;
    int *s1 = difference(setA, sizeA, setB, sizeB, &size1);
    int *s2 = intersection(setA, sizeA, setB, sizeB, &size2);
    int *s3 = difference(setB, sizeB, setA, sizeA, &size3);
    int *set = malloc(sizeof(int) * (size1 + size2 + size3));
    *size = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        set[*(size)++] = s1[i];
    for(i = 0; i < size2; i++)
        set[*(size)++] = s2[i];
    for(i = 0; i < size3; i++)
        set[*(size)++] = s3[i];

    return set;
}

void main() {
    int *setA, *setB, *setC;
    int sizeA, sizeB, size;

    printf("Enter the size of set A and B : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &sizeA, &sizeB);

    setA = malloc(sizeof(int)*sizeA);
    setB = malloc(sizeof(int)*sizeB);

    printf("Enter the values in set A :\n");
    input_set(setA, sizeA);

    printf("Enter the values in set B :\n");
    input_set(setB, sizeB);

    printf("A union B = ");
    setC = un(setA, sizeA, setB, sizeB, &size);
    display_set(setC, size);

    printf("A intersection B = ");
    setC = intersection(setA, sizeA, setB, sizeB, &size);
    display_set(setC, size);

    printf("A - B = ");
    setC = difference(setA, sizeA, setB, sizeB, &size);
    display_set(setC, size);

    printf("B - A = ");
    setC = difference(setB, sizeB, setA, sizeA, &size);
    display_set(setC, size);
}
```

Any help or even comments about code quality is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: WOw! Only if I did that before.

Comment: Too much code.  Need to narrow it way down.

Comment: Found error in *(size)++
Looks like ++ has higher precedence than *

Comment: Can anyone still tell me how awful that code is.

Answer (score 6):

```
toto.c:25:54: warning: operator '?:' has lower precedence than '*'; '*' will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
    int *setC = malloc(sizeof(int) * (sizeA < sizeB) ? sizeA : sizeB);
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

I think compiling with a better compiler and with warnings activated would give you some good pointers...

Comment: Beat me to it. My eye was immediately attracted to that part of the code just because it was so unusual, and my mighty intellect found the answer.

Comment: That wasn't the exact problem there.
Why is this getting upvoted?

Comment: @user3882877: because that snippet of code is absolute garbage and is (a) impossible to understand and (b) susceptible to mistakes, as the warnings show.

Comment: So you mean like I should be running something like splint and make sure not a single warning shows up?
@DavidTitarenco

Comment: @user3882877 if you're compiling with gcc, add the `-Wall` and `-Werror` flags. The first one shows all warnings and the second one makes it so compilation will fail with any warnings possible. You should really never have warnings.

Comment: Really. That's sounds like so much more edits I should do.
Great!

Comment: Hey @RickyMutschlechner those two flags displayed just the classic `void main()` error which I changed to return type `int`
I'm seriously thinking about splint
Will that be good or just increase the work awfully?

Comment: @user3882877 I've never used it. Also, if you have zero warnings and you're still getting a seg fault, that's just strange. Are you positive you're running the latest version? Delete the executable and recompile just to be safe. And edit the code with your latest version so we can try to help.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner No, no. no. The code is nicely executing. I actually commented about that in the question.
I'm not getting anything now with the compiler options.
I'm just thinking about reaching the best code quality.
What further changes you'd make to the code just so there's more readability?

Comment: @user3882877 if the code is working now, accept this answer and repost the working code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/